# Ionic 2 app build error.:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, ionic2

The error is as follow 
" * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>    Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc;"

Can any one help

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is something which went wrong in your `android` setup.

Try removing the `android` folder from your directory in `platforms`

And then try running `cordova platform add android`

Then try building the app again